# Appending an Array and String in javascript into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can you run a getelementbyid on an Array and a String in Javascript and set it as a variable that is not null for example foo["dog"] x = getelementbyid(foo[0]+"food") and now x = dogfood

```
<script>
  var myrows = new Array();   

  $(function() {
    $("#check").click(function(){
      myrows=[]
      $(".head input:checked").not("#selectall").each(function(){
        myrows.push($(this).parent().attr("id"));
      }).value;

      alert(myrows);
    });   

    $("#subbut").click(function(){
      var x;
      var r=confirm("Are you sure you?");

      if (r==true){
        x="You pressed OK!";
      }else{
        Object.cancel;
      }

      **alert( myrows[0]+"servername" + " before" );

      for(var i =0; i< myrows.length; i++){
        alert(myrows[i] +"rootname" +" in loop" );
        var j= document.getElementById(xmyrows[i] +"rootname" );
        alert(j+" after call" );
        var y = document.getElementById(myrows[i]+"servername");

        document.getElementById("id_rootname").value= j.textContent;
        document.getElementById("id_servername").value= y.textContent ;**

        $.post($("#forms").attr("action"), $("#forms").serialize(), function(data) {

        });
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: you would need an iframe target on the form in order to avoid a refresh

Comment: You can only submit one form unless you use ajax to pass the form data to the server

Comment: I am working in django there has to be a way to submit multiple forms on 1 button click

Comment: you can submit multiple forms on one click.. solution is  Ajax...

Comment: Is ajax my only solution? I have been running from adding another thing to my many django libraries.

Comment: Also the submit button is running an sql query and posting data to MSql2008 if that helps

Comment: Yes AJAX is your only solution if you want that done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen because java script allows white spaces sometimes if a string is concatenated with a number. try removing the spaces and create a string and then pass it into getElementById.

example:

```
var str = myrows[i]+"rootname";

str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

var str1 = myrows[i]+"servername";

str1 = str1.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
var j= document.getElementById(str);
var y = document.getElementById(str1);

document.getElementById("id_rootname").value= j.textContent;

document.getElementById("id_servername").value= y.textContent ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the array/string problem is, but from the comments it seems you're looking for a way to do dynamic form submission: Dan Davis has provided the nuts and bolts of the solution [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708096/appending-an-array-and-string-in-javascript-into-a-variable#comment-25806447) — for each form you need to submit dynamically (without a refresh), create an iframe, then set the respective form's target attribute to that iframe's ID:

```
<form id="form1" target="#form1Response">
    ...
</form>
<form id="form2" target="#form2Response">
    ...
</form>
<iframe id="#form1Response"></iframe>
<iframe id="#form2Response"></iframe>
```

You will then need to attach your server response callbacks to the various iframes' `load` events. Beware though: even an empty iframe fires a load event, so you will need to filter false positives (empty iframe contents) in your callback.

Another caveat: if your server responds with JSON, IE will prompt the user to save the response to the filesystem before your script can intercept — so make sure the MIME type heading is set to text/plain or text/html to make sure the response is loaded into the iframe's DOM.

Comment: I already figured out how to dynamic form submissions the issue is i need to fill in text boxes with data and var j= document.getElementById(myrows[i].valueOf() +"rootname" ); is returning that my j is null when it should be row#rootname.